# What are the main differences between a traditional receiver-operating curve and a Lorenz curve?

Tags: roc, diagnostic, lorenz-curve

I am analyzing a dataset of cardiac echocardiographic exams, aiming to compare the diagnostic accuracy of a novel test in comparison to a standard one.

I have recognized that using Stata I can generate using the very same set of data (thus including 2 binary variables) a standard receiver-operating characteristic curve, but also a Lorenz curve.

**Which are the main differences between the two? Can they be interpreted in a similar fashion?**